# How to ORDER BY a field consisting of digits following by alphabets in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How to ORDER BY a field consisting of digits following by alphabets, such as `10s`, in MySQL? The desired order is:

- digits, e.g., `10`
- digits+alphabets, e.g., `10s`

For instance,

```
# Original data:
1
10
105
109
10s

# Desired results
1
10
10s
105
109
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT values FROM Table ORDER BY CAST(values AS UNSIGNED), values;
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
ORDER BY CAST(alphanum AS UNSIGNED), alphanum
```

... or, slightly more concise:

```
ORDER BY alphanum + 0, alphanum
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4c5/5).